# Issue passing argument to ansible ssh

Tags: ssh, ansible, ansible-inventory

Below ssh connectivity works fine:

```
ssh -i /opt/cert/id_rsa_prod targetuser@targethost -t bash
```

My ansible host file has the below entry

```
[target*]

targethost ansible_python_interpreter=/opt/bin/python2.7 ansible_ssh_extra_args="-t bash" ansible_ssh_common_args="-t" ansible_ssh_private_key_file=/opt/cert/id_rsa_prod USER_RUN=targetuser
```

When I run this ansible playbook it fails to connect to target host and throws the below error output:

> 23:53:42  ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: targetuser
>
> 23:53:42  SSH: EXEC ssh -vvv -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o
>   ControlPersist=60s -o 'IdentityFile="/opt/cert/id_rsa_prod"' -o
>   KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o
>   PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey
>   -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o User=targetuser -o ConnectTimeout=10 -t bash -o ControlPath=/home/sourceuser/.ansible/cp/e8313d01d6 targethost '/bin/sh -c '"'"'echo ~targetuser && sleep 0'"'"''
>
> 23:53:42  (255, '', 'OpenSSH_7.7p1 (CentrifyDC build
>   5.5.1-395) , OpenSSL 1.0.2o-fips  27 Mar 2018\r\ndebug1: Reading configuration data /home/sourceuser/.ssh/config\r\ndebug1: Reading
>   configuration data /etc/centrifydc/ssh/ssh_config\r\ndebug1:
>   /etc/centrifydc/ssh/ssh_config line 3: Applying options for
>   *\r\ndebug1: auto-mux: Trying existing master\r\ndebug1: Control socket "/home/sourceuser/.ansible/cp/e8313d01d6" does not
>   exist\r\ndebug2: resolving "bash" port 22\r\nssh: Could not resolve
>   hostname bash: Name or service not known\r\n')
>
> 23:53:42 fatal: [targethost]: UNREACHABLE! => {
>
> 23:53:42     "changed": false,
>
> 23:53:42     "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh:
>   OpenSSH_7.7p1 (CentrifyDC build 5.5.1-395) , OpenSSL 1.0.2o-fips  27
>   Mar 2018\r\ndebug1: Reading configuration data
>   /home/sourceuser/.ssh/config\r\ndebug1: Reading configuration data
>   /etc/centrifydc/ssh/ssh_config\r\ndebug1:
>   /etc/centrifydc/ssh/ssh_config line 3: Applying options for
>   *\r\ndebug1: auto-mux: Trying existing master\r\ndebug1: Control socket \"/home/sourceuser/.ansible/cp/e8313d01d6\" does not
>   exist\r\ndebug2: resolving \"bash\" port 22\r\nssh: Could not resolve
>   hostname bash: Name or service not known\r\n",
>
> 23:53:42     "unreachable": true
>
> 23:53:42 }
>
> 23:53:42       to retry, use: --limit
>   @/opt/scripts/myfolder/site.retry
>
> 23:53:42
>
> 23:53:42 PLAY RECAP
>
> ---
>
> 23:53:42 targethost   : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=1    failed=0

Can you please suggest how to fix the connectivity issue ?

Comment: "Could not resolve hostname bash: Name or service not known" how is that confusing to you? The command line clearly shows the `-t bash` right in the middle of the `-o` options to ssh

Comment: If you understand ansible; that is something constructed by ansible tool and not me. Hence, I was looking for a solution as to how we can get ansible construct the correct ssh connection